# Running one action on multiple sprites simultaneously

Tags: animation, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d

I have created a spiraling animation for a football. I want to be able to run it on 2 sprites simultaneously.

This is what I have done:

```
CCAnimation* footballAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithFrame:@"Football" frameCount:60 delay:0.005f];
spiral = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:footballAnim];
CCRepeatForever* repeat = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:spiral];
[Sprite1 runAction: repeat];
[Sprite2 runAction: repeat];
```

However, the action is only run on the first sprite. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Actions (sadly) can't be re-used or run multiple times. Instead you'll have to instantiate two actions or copy an existing one.

Something like this should work:

```
[Sprite1 runAction: [repeat copy]];
[Sprite2 runAction: repeat];
```

Comment: thanks you save my night i got idea from this      pointer->runAction(rep->clone());
    knifeHand->runAction(rep);